# What does "ISO standard equivalent" actually mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, terminology, sql-standard

I'm reading about comparison operators. In the documentation, [Comparison Operators Modified by ANY, SOME, or ALL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187074(v=sql.105)) it says (emphasis added):

> Comparison operators that introduce a subquery can be modified by the
>   keywords ALL or ANY. **SOME is an ISO standard equivalent for ANY.**

What does this mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It just means that operator `SOME` is not some MS proprietary extension. It is part of the (ISO/ANSI) [SQL standard](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=53681).